# R: gDistance Transition Function for Wind Data

Tags: r, transition, distance, r-raster

I would like to calculate the shortest path for a sailing vessel from port A to B using the `shortestPath()` function from the `gDistance` package in `R`. The ocean in between the two ports is described by a raster of grid cells. The optimal path depends on two variables: wind direction and wind speed (both given by raster layers). The wind direction and the angle from which I enter the respective cell determine whether I face head- or tailwind. In case of headwind my travel cost increases with wind speed and under tailwind the travel cost decreases with wind speed.

The problem here is that I did not figure out how to create a transition function from the two variables direction and speed. The transition function (and transition layer) is the key element required by the `shortestPath()` function in determining the optimal way. Apparently, the most common application for `shortestPath()` is elevation data which is a lot easier to handle since you only have to account for a single variable, altitude.

Any ideas are most welcome.

Comment: If you are considering wind direction and speed, then you need to consider at least two more variables: own-speed (e.g., boat) and time, since the wind is variable. (I'm assuming you are not considering wind-at-altitude, which brings in many other aviation optimization challenges.) This is an optimization problem, and not a trivial (LP) one at that. Since you aren't including code, data, and errors in said code, I suggest it is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I know that many more variables can be included. However, for this application I want to keep the model simplistic. Wind direction and wind speed are assumed to be time-constant.
The question is not about how the optimization works in a mathematical sense (which is which did not post it on CrossValidated or Math SE). My question specifically targets the mechanics of the `shortestPath()` function in `R`. Others have used this function for similarly complex applications. The only prerequisite is to come up with the code for the transition function. The optimization is handled automatically.

Comment: Ok, simplifications are certainly fair. I haven't tried yet, but the [`gdistance` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/gdistance1.pdf) mentions that the user can *"define a function f(i,j)  to  calculate the transition value for each pair of adjacent cells i and j"* (p3), suggesting that you have full control over the adjacency matrix, and it is sensitive to effective head/tail wind change entering cells.